# Make a UIAlertView show after second launch

Tags: ios, xcode, uialertview

If that isn't possible, then how may I do it after, say, 3 minutes of app usage? This is going to be used for a Rate Us alert but I would rather the user have some time to actually use the app before it asks for them to rate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options {
    // ...
    if ([self plusPlusLaunchCount] == 2) {
        [self showRateUsAlert];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)showRateUsAlert {
    // show the Rate Us alert view
}

- (NSInteger)plusPlusLaunchCount {
    static NSString *Key = @"launchCount";
    NSInteger count = 1 + [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:Key];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:count forKey:Key];
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Would this go in my appdelegate or just the first view or?

Comment: `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is a `UIApplicationDelegate` message.

Comment: Ah I see that now, suppose I should have looked in my AppDelegate. Thanks.

Comment: It's throwing this warning, anything to be concerned with?: Conflicting return type in implementation of 'application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:': 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') vs 'void'

Comment: Oops.  Change it to return BOOL, and return YES.

Comment: Can you update your answer? It's still giving me issues. Sorry, I'm a little new at this.

Comment: I don't get why I am still receiving this: Conflicting return type in implementation of 'application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:': 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') vs 'void'

On this line: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options {

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making a "Rate Us" alert yourself, why don't you use third-party libraries? This kind of thing has been done so many times anyway.

This is one of a really good one : [iRate](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate)

Not exactly answer to your question in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an `NSTimer` for the time interval you want to show the alert. When the application launches start the timer and after the interval you set finishes, display the alert.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use DidBecomeActive which is called every time you launch app, and come from background/sleep mode:

You would need to cancel the timer in case user doesn't use app for so long.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.    

    rateUsTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:180 
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(showRateUsAlert) 
                                   userInfo:nil 
                                    repeats:NO] retain];


}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{
   [rateUsTimer_ invalidate];
   [rateUsTimer_ release];
   rateUsTimer = nil;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
   [rateUsTimer_ invalidate];
   [rateUsTimer_ release];
   rateUsTimer = nil;
}


- (void)showRateUsAlert {
    //Here you present alert
    [rateUsTimer_ release];
    rateUsTimer = nil;
}
```