# How can i detect 3rd time app launch

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I want to show an alertview on third time my app is launched. I have searched everywhere but can't find the solution. How can I know that my app has been launched for the third time?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: why not you store the launch count in NSUserDefault when ever your application did launch method is fired

Comment: save a nsnumber to nsuserdefaults. at each launch increment it, when you reach 3, do your voodoo.

Comment: @manjitsingh you can create a count and check for the third launch using the count. Plz c my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use these methods to read and write to file with very little effort

```
+ (void) setSetting: (NSString *)key value: (NSString *)value {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:value forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key]]; 
[defaults synchronize];
}

+ (NSString *) getSetting: (NSString *)key defaultVal: (NSString *)defaultVal {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *setting = [defaults stringForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key]];
if (setting == nil) {
    setting = defaultVal;
}

return setting;
}
```

you can just update a value you have stored in the user defaults each time the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your appDelegate is triggered

Answer (score 2):

Thats easy. Save an NSNumber in your NSUserDefaults and increase it every time you're launching your application. When it hits 3 then show an alert.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options {
// ...
if ([self plusPlusLaunchCount] == 3) {
    [self showRateUsAlert];
}
return YES;
}

- (void)showRateUsAlert {
// show the Rate Us alert view
}

- (NSInteger)plusPlusLaunchCount {
static NSString *Key = @"launchCount";
NSInteger count = 1 + [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:Key];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:count forKey:Key];
return count;
}
```

Comment: Hint: [make-a-uialertview-show-after-second-launch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076960/make-a-uialertview-show-after-second-launch)